# Need some design pointers on async communication between microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices, system-design

I have a use-case where clients need to interact with different entities which are owned by different microservices. But these entities are actually dependent on prior one for their creation.
eg : MicroService1 owns data1
Microservice2 owns data2 (data2 creation requires data1)
Microservice3 owns data3 (data3 creation requires data2)

The communication is async between MicroService1 --> Microservice2 --> Microservice3

Now, client needs to interact with data1 and data3. This is actually leading to classic problems in distributed env where client needs to interact with data3 just after ingesting data1, but data1 has not reached MicroService2 and then eventually data2 hasn't reached Microservice, so system doesn't have data3 yet.

One last resort for me is to make the flow synchronous to handle the usecase or to introduce calculated waits. But I was hoping if there's any design pattern/reference where I can handle the scenario while retaining the async nature of communication between the services.

for context, Data1 here is a purchase order, data2 is items and its prices in the purchase order and data3 is the invoice (created on a decided frequency) containing all the items from multiple such purchase orders. Clients will stream the purchase orders and expect the invoices for them.  So there are multiple race conditions that can happen. Client would expect a particular purchase order to be invoiced but it is still under processing. the purchase order that needs to be clubbed in a running invoice hasn't even reached the Microservice3. or even worse, the purchase order has a newer version v2, with some extra items, but Microservice2 has only processed items for v1 and now the invoice creation would end up using v1 instead of v2.  this is because we are processing at event level, but if call would have been sync, we would have received v2 before creating the invoice

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem description is a bit abstract, so it is hard to come with a concrete suggestion.

> The communication is async between MicroService1 --> Microservice2 --> Microservice3

"async communication" sounds like you can communicating by *publishing* a message on a e.g. Kafka Topic, and the *consumer* listen to that topic.

> Now, client needs to interact with data1 and data3.

So if consumers listen to the `topic_for_data3`, they can "lookup" data1 or also subscribe to `topic_for_data1` since data1 is already available when data3 is published.

From the abstract problem description, it is hard to be more concrete than this. But this may be one way to do it.

Comment: yes, by async, I meant publishing events. We are using AWS SNS-SQS for that.

Comment: Hi Jonas, added the context in the question. instead of editing the question, clicked on edit link for the answer initially :P